# Publishing Multiple Sites in a Web Role

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-cloud-services

We have tried following article to support multiple sites in a Web Role, but its not working.

https://michaelcollier.wordpress.com/2013/01/14/multiple-sites-in-a-web-role/

The problem is the physical directory path where cspack takes all the files inside that directory blindly (not the proper published one) if we mention the directory as csproj directory. The hack mentioned in this article to update ccproj to publish secondary site is not working since schema has changed in later Azure SDK, this article is pretty old referring SDK 1.3.

Any suggestions/guidance?

Comment: does this help? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg557553.aspx#Bindings and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg557553.aspx#Sites and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg557553.aspx#Endpoints , also read the write up in a different perspective, as it might give you a better idea perhaps? http://blog.elastacloud.com/2011/01/11/azure-running-multiple-web-sites-in-a-single-webrole/

Comment: yet another example : https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/multiple-secured-sites-one-web-role-windows-azure-mukul-k-gupta?forceNoSplash=true